# Why do I have to enter my password twice when changing proxy settings?

Tags: proxy, settings, gconf

When I change the proxy settings and apply them system-wide, I always have to enter my super-user password, as anyone could expect.

However, I have to do that twice : once for "proxy settings" and another time for "Gconf". How do I set this up so that I have to enter my password only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why is difficult to answer (could be just decision during the design), and it will probably be fixed - per this [Brainstorm Idea](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/2813/).

While its not fixed, you can try to prevent to enter password twice if you follow up the instuction from this bug [#507095](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/507095).